# Citation undefined in Biblatex-mla

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I am a mac user and I installed biblatex-mla into `~/Library/texmf` and I `texhash`ed a lot. However my citation never works.

Here is my tex file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibl1.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    keywords = {primary},
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@book{knuth84,
    keywords = {primary},
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title= "The {TeX}book",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = 1984
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibl2.bib}
@unpublished{patashnik88,
    keywords = {secondary},
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "Using {BibTeX}",
    note = "Documentation for general BibTeX users",
    month = jan,
    year = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla,guessmedium=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibl1.bib}
\addbibresource{bibl2.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth84}, \cite{goossens93}, \cite{patashnik88}

\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

I am sure I included my `bib` file in the current directory. Below is the log:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Missing 'hyperref' package.
(biblatex)                Setting hyperref=false.
(./Writing Draft.aux) (./Writing Draft.bbl)
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'knuth84' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'goossens93' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'patashnik88' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'primary' not found on input line 41.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 41.
Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'secondary' not found on input line 43.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 43.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Writing Draft.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Writing Draft"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
)</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on "Writing Draft.pdf" (1 page, 21282 bytes).
SyncTeX written on "Writing Draft.synctex.gz"
Transcript written on "Writing Draft.log".
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you run Biber?

Comment: @JosephWright I am pretty new to LaTeX. I use TexShop to run commands automatically. What is Biber BTW?

Comment: biber is a replacement for bibtex, specially written for biblatex. By default, all recent versions of biblatex output information for biber, not bibtex. To use bibtex, you must specify the `"backend=bibtex"` option to biblatex. To use biber, you just run it in the same way as you would bibtex. For example, if your file is called "file", you run "latex file" followed by "biber file" and then "latex file" again (perhaps twice if you are prompted to do so).

Comment: @PLK It seems have a warning that something is not specified and use biber by default. How to specify backend=bibtex?

Comment: Change your biblatex package loading line to `\usepackage[style=mla,guessmedium=false,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}`

Comment: @PLK Though this warning disappeared, it still says "Citation not found"

Comment: are you running bibtex after the first latex run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after I delete the space in filename and `\usepackage[style=mla,guessmedium=false,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}`. Weird.